# "error: libmmd.dll: no such file or directory" when compiling a Python exe with py2exe

Tags: python, dll, exe

When trying to compile an exe file using py2exe, I get the error "libmmd.dll: no such file or directory."

I have successfully made an exe of a script that just displays "Hello world!", but for some reason the file I'm working with won't go.

Here are the imports in the file I'm trying to make an exe:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
```

Here's the setup script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['pb_play3.py'])
```

I call the setup script:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

And it shows a lot of code in PowerShell until it displays the error.

I don't really know how DLLs work, but based on the Googling I've done it seems I shouldn't be moving them or downloading them from the Internet(?).

Also, when I search Windows Explorer for that DLL it says it's in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core. Both the setup file and the file to be exe are in C:\scripts\mystuff. Is there a way to make libmmd accessible to py2exe? Or am I misunderstanding it altogether? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I added

```
import numpy
```

to both the file to be compiled to exe and the setup.py file. Now it returns

```
error: libzmq.dll: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

I think its need numpy. If yes then import numpy within setup.py resolved the issue

Comment: Interesting! I added import numpy to both the file to be exe and the setup file. Now it returns "error: libzmq.dll: No such file or directory."

Comment: You can move libzmq in file path